# how can i display output in label continuously from weighing scale using c#

Tags: c#, winforms

i'm new in Visual Studio 2010 (C#). My code using is working properly, and the output was displayed on richTextBox but my problem is I want to display the output on label.

My current settings:

> Baud rate:9600
>
> Parity:none
>
> Data bits:8
>
> Stop bits:1

Previous code:

```
rtfTerminal.Invoke(new EventHandler(delegate
{
    rtfTerminal.SelectedText = string.Empty;
    rtfTerminal.SelectionFont = new Font(rtfTerminal.SelectionFont, FontStyle.Bold);
    rtfTerminal.SelectionColor = LogMsgTypeColor[(int)msgtype];
    rtfTerminal.AppendText(msg);
    rtfTerminal.ScrollToCaret();
}));
```

And I try to change it but the display is blinking
this is my code:

```
private void Log(LogMsgType msgtype, string msg)
{
    label2.Invoke(new EventHandler(delegate
    {          
        label2.Text = msg;
    }));
}
```

Help me pls! Thanks!

Comment: @DanielA.White yes! winforms

Comment: @yuyu Do you want to show above 4 item in single label?

Comment: Without [a good, _minimal_, _complete_ code example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that reliably reproduces the problem, it's impossible to know for sure what you're even asking. But it sounds like you are concerned about flickering when you update the `Label` text rapidly. If so, you need to double-buffer the control, so that the actual update happens off-screen. There are numerous questions on Stack Overflow already that explain how to do that.

Comment: @Peter: I believe that Label is double-buffered by default. Maybe it is sitting on a Control that needs buffering, too, like a Panel?

Comment: @TaW: yes, I don't recall for sure, but it's possible. Ultimately, that's the reason a good code example is required. There's not even enough information here to know for sure this is in fact a redraw/double-buffering issue. It sounds like it is, but I would want a good code example before spending any real effort trying to figure out the specifics.

Comment: Where is the Label located? On the form or neseted somewhere? What is the estimated frequncy of the updates?

Answer (score 0):

C# code is here

```
private delegate void SetTextCallback2(string text);

private void SetText2(string text)
{
    try {
        if (this.RichTextBox1.InvokeRequired) {
            SetTextCallback2 d = new SetTextCallback2(SetText2);
            this.Invoke(d, new object[] { text });

        } else {
            this.RichTextBox1.Text = text;
            result = text.Split(stringSeparators);
            TextBox1.Text = result.ElementAt(4);
            TextBox2.Text = result.ElementAt(8);
            TextBox3.Text = result.ElementAt(12);

        }


    } catch (Exception ex) {
    }

}
```

Answer (score -1):

try following code

```
Private Delegate Sub SetTextCallback2(ByVal text As String)

    Private Sub SetText2(ByVal text As String)
        Try
            If Me.RichTextBox1.InvokeRequired Then
                Dim d As New SetTextCallback2(AddressOf SetText2)
                Me.Invoke(d, New Object() {text})
            Else

                Me.RichTextBox1.Text = text
                result = text.Split(stringSeparators)
                    TextBox1.Text = result.ElementAt(4)
                    TextBox2.Text = result.ElementAt(8)
                    TextBox3.Text = result.ElementAt(12)

            End If


        Catch ex As Exception
        End Try

    End Sub
```

Also try timer and background worker controls to invoke your Log function with specified time interval.

refer these link for more knowledge

http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/361285/Serial-Port-Communication

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.ports.serialport(v=vs.110).aspx

Hope this helps to get your work done :)

Comment: The question is tagged C#. Please fix your answer so that you are answering using C#.